# Java object validation for dynamic object Hashmap?

Tags: java, validation, jackson, jaxb

We have a MQTT listener which receives messages which we need to validate syntactically. So we have one such object:

**Data Model:**

```
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "content",
     })
    public class Content
        implements ToString2
    {
        ...////
  
        @XmlElement(required = true)
        protected Object content;
    }
```

The Data model is generated from XSD (XML schema document), hence has JAXB annotations.

So when deserialized to an Java Object, the `content` is mapped to a dynamic `HashMap`. Example the payload:

```
 "content": {
    
        "devID":<String value>,
    
        "lng": < decimal value>
    
        }
```

Now we have a `HashMap` populated with above JSON which we have to validate. There can be multiple payloads like this for which we need the validation i.e in each the `content` will be a different set of `Key, Value`.

What will be the best way to achieve such validation ??

We are not using `Spring` Framework, we have `Jboss/EJB` container currently.